# How can I create a Windows password reset disk on Mac?

Tags: windows, password

I have installed a dual-system on my Mac: Windows and Mac. Unfortunately, I forgot the password to login Windows OS and cannot access it. Is there any possible way to create a Windows password reset disk on MacOS，so that I could crack Windows password without reinstall?

Answer (score 2):

Use Hiren's Boot CD. it have a password deleter. you can download it for free and just need to burn it to a CD.

Answer (score 1):

The password reset disk could only be created from the Control Panel inside the Windows system. You can boot into MacOS and download the ISO image of Offline NT Password & Registry Editor, then burn the CD using the built-in Disk Utility tool. Or create a bootableb USB with the freeware UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the password reset disk while you still know the password, unfortunately. But there are other ways to rescue your Windows environment.